# How to do a login with Node using Mean.io stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm developing a webapp using stack MEAN.io and for now I have got the frontend part with HTML, CSS and AngularJS with some logic in it. But now I want to do login on server side and I don't know where to start because for example AngularJS it has the file where it defines the routes, what templete it will be used and which controller as well but what about the Express/Node part?

How can I implement this new login? I'm kinda lost.

[image: Server folders]

I want to do some "administration" with registered users that they can add favourite profiles. Like add one bookmark to right side of screen. But I want to do this in server side.

The problem is I do not find where to write the server side code and this relationate with the same file to the frontend.

For example when I am at Index page so I want to show the favourites profile i added before. And stored to MongoDB of course.

Comment: This is pretty broad, are there any more details you can provide?

Comment: Done. I don't know if this is more clear now. In a resume i want to write code to server side but i cannot find where to connect it with the angularJS part.

Comment: I see - I can't write a full answer on this, but you'd be looking at creating some kind of server-side API (if you're using Express, this is [super quick](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method)), and using Angular's [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) module to send requests to it.

Comment: I understant but when I want to run my project I go to my main folder and write " gulp " and that run all server (I think) so I imagine that already built the server-side API right?

And I already use the $http dependency because my project uses API requests from Riot Games API.

Comment: Depends on what's in your `gulpfile.js` - typically it's used to compile stuff into bundles and run code checks, but it's been a while since I've used it.  It won't build any code (APIs) for you though - you will need to program the part of your application that favourites a profile in whichever way your application needs it.

Comment: Ah, if you're using a third-party API, just look through their docs and see which requests you should be making from `$http` from the client side.  I thought you were storing and serving data from your own servers.

Comment: I don't want to you make the code. I want to do it and learn about it. My problem it's I don't know where to start to write the code. I have to create on a server side like index.js and creat you showed me in the first comment? I'm in a hastle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options use regular forms to post data or use $http angular ajax post.

> regular form kind of posting data to server

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type"email" name="email" />
  <input type"password" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

> posting data using ajax angular $http method

```
<form >
  <input type"email" ng-model="user.email" />
  <input type"password" ng-model="user.password" />
  <button ng-click="login">login</button>
</form>

$scope.user = {};
$scope.login= function () {
   $http({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        email: user.email,
        password:user.password
      }
   });
});
```

> server side

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  //custom authentication or use passport.js
});
```

Comment: So.. when you are in '/' route the code inside router.post it will be executed and then I will be able to write my functionalities in there right?

and the code you wrote in server side at server/controllers?

Comment: form action="/" or $http url: 'http://localhost:3000/' must post to proper back-end function which is router.post('/').It has nothing to do with angular routing.Yes can write your functionalities in controllers and module.exports them to routes.